# Django passing parameter to html, get same content in for-loop

Tags: django, templates, for-loop

I tried to pass parameter from django backend to html through render. But I got the same content in each loop:

```
{% for c in songList %}
    <tr>
        <td id="sid-td-{{forloop.counter}}">{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
        <td id="sname-td-{{forloop.counter}}" class="title">{{ c.name }}</td>
        <td id="sartist-td-{{forloop.counter}}">{{ c.artist }}</td>
        <td id="suploader-td-{{forloop.counter}}">{{ c.uploader }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The songList is a list of son objects. The generated html content is like this:

```
<tr>
   <td id="sid-td-1">1</td>
   <td id="sname-td-1" class="title">Heart of the Refuge</td>
   <td id="sartist-td-1">Matthew Lien</td>
   <td id="suploader-td-1">Kingston</td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td id="sid-td-2">2</td>
   <td id="sname-td-2" class="title">Heart of the Refuge</td>
   <td id="sartist-td-2">Matthew Lien</td>
   <td id="suploader-td-2">Kingston</td>
</tr>
```

In the database query result, those two records are different. However, in the generated html, the rendered content is the same.

Anyone knows why and how to fix it?

Comment: can you your views that renders this data?

Comment: can you print the ids in html?

Comment: Oh sorry, I've found the problem. It's in the backend. Please ignore this question..